# How can I fix this and add multiple dropdown?

Tags: html, css

i'm very new with coding and I'm trying to learning.
This is my problem. I want to do a top nav bar, but because of contents I need "more than one" dropdown.

I'm learning using the w3school their example is good, I've tried adding other options but, it doesn't respect the CSS. Why?
I can't understand :(

I'm a very very newbie, and I've been searching about that, but maybe my mistake is very little and I don't know "what exactly" I need to searching for. So if already the answer was posted, please sorry

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Page 2</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 2</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 3</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Extra</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 4</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}
li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a dropdown inside an option of a dropdown? If yes then check this : http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: no, is not that. nothing of bootstrap. only html and css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have done the main part. Just do the same for any dropDown you want.

I mean, you should add  class="dropdown" to the parent

Then, add your dropDown div

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
}
li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}
li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Page 2</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>


<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 3</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Extra</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 4</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

For example, I changed this:

```
<li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 2</li>
```

to this:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: but why the other options are black and not white? 
I mean, there are inside the ul, I think they should respect what is inside 
ul li a {

Comment: @Lantis, I just did one more for example.
Do the same for anyone you want. look at the end of my updated answer

Comment: @Lantis, glad to hear. Please upvote and select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You were so close.

The problem comes from your `a` tag. You have to surround the text with your `a` tag.

The CSS wasn't apply because some of the css is applied only on `a` element. And you put noting inside.

**Your code:**

```
<li><a href="#"></a>Dropdown 2</li>
```

**The solution:**

```
<li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
```

**Live example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2ep3a8dh/

Comment: You'r welcome ;) Here a link to help you to mark the question as solved http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235